# How to fill with null value a table type within a table type

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, null, nullable

I want to fill with null value in a table type inside another type (Oracle).
I will Just write the code and it will be easier to explain the problem.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE type_1 is record (col_1 varchar2(255),
                         col_2 varchar2(30),
                         col_3 varchar2(3)
                        );
  TYPE table_1_tbl is table of type_1;

  TYPE table_2 is record (col_1 varchar2(255),
                          col_2 varchar2(30),
                          t1    table_1_tbl
                         );
  TYPE table_2_tbl is table of table_2;

  TYPE type_3 is record (col_1 varchar2(30),
                         col_2 VARCHAR2(19),
                         t2    table_2_tbl
                        );
  TYPE table_3_tbl is table of type_3;

  Obj table_3_tbl;

BEGIN
    select 
           'value_1', 
           'value_2',
           null
      BULK COLLECT INTO 
           Obj
      FROM dual;
END;
/
```

This code results in the following:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 32, column 16:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

As you can see, Oracle won't let me use NULL value to fill the "t3" column of my variable "obj". Do you guys know how can I do this?

NOTE: I am NOT ALLOWED to compile these types in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
...
BEGIN
  obj := new table_3_tbl();
  obj.extend(1);
  obj(1).col_1 := 'value_1';
  obj(1).col_2 := 'value_2';
  obj(1).t2    := NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I will get the values from a query, I just used the dual table as an example. But thanks anyway!